# How to use regex in form.py in django

Tags: python, django, regex

I am working on Django project. I a fetching the data from POSTgresql in form.py while fetching the data is comming in  ('Shirur'), in such format but i want the data as Shirur.

```
Taluka1=forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data.objects.values_list("taluka").distinct())
Gut_Number = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data.objects.all().values("gut_number").distinct())
Village_Name_Revenue = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=data.objects.all().values("village_name_revenue").distinct())
```

above is my code
'

Comment: can you write an example of input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

just use  in the paramters
flat=true and empty_label=None

```
Taluka = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=data.objects.values_list("taluka", flat=True).distinct(), empty_label=None)
print(Taluka, "Taluka in forms")
Gut_Number = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=data.objects.values_list("gut_number").distinct())
Village_Name_Revenue = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=data.objects.values_list("village_name_revenue").distinct())
```